ROS2 URDF/gazebo reverse the parent/child joint relationship
I work with ros2 on a robot crawler arm where the start or end may become fixed or the end effector at any point (inspire from this robot : https://news.mit.edu/2019/robots-large-structures-little-pieces-1016).
the robot is build this way : world -> base(fixed) -> L1 -> J0 -> L2 -> J2 -> L3 -> J3 -> L4 -> J4 -> L5 -> J5 -> L6
I work from a code where the reverse of the links is working but the relation parent/child is still the same (parent : Ln/child : Ln+1).
I'm new to ROS2 and i have some  questions :

is it possible to reverse the parent/child relationship or urdf/gazebo plugins won't allow it because it's already declare in the urdf file ?
can i create virtual joint where the parent/child relationship is reverse (P:Ln/C:Ln+1 => P:Ln+1/C:Ln) or will it be conflict with the former joint ?

Any thoughts appreciated! Thanks
